# How to redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS with GCP Load Balancer

Tags: load-balancing, google-cloud-platform

I've setup the standard GCP load balancer to point to my instance group. It talks over the same port on the instance. I would like to redirect http to https. I would normally do this in nginx or apache on the instance but that won't work since its https already from the load balancer.

Is there a way to rewrite the url similar to if I was using [nginx and apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083221/how-to-redirect-all-http-requests-to-https) to load balance in GCP's Load Balancer? or should I forward http and https to the instance and have the instance handle the rewrite as I normally would. I'm new to GCP thanks in advance.

Comment: ever figure this out?

Comment: Naturally I found a great answer right after adding this bounty! Anyone who wants to do a nice writeup of http://serverfault.com/questions/733166/redirect-all-http-traffic-to-https-when-using-the-https-load-balancer-on-googl or just link this question there can have my points!

Answer (score 4):

You can set it up the same way as Nginx does. When you see traffic on a port which is not https, you redirect it to HTTPs.

To do this, you can use `X-Forwarded-Proto` header which contains the protocol using which the traffic came in. On your server, you can simply look for traffic that has `http` header and upgrade that request to `HTTPS`.

Most commonly used way is to use `301` redirect, but that is not a great practice. One should use HTTP `426` upgrade request header.

Read more: [Is HTTP status code 426 Upgrade Required only meant signal an upgrade to a secure channel is required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873247/is-http-status-code-426-upgrade-required-only-meant-signal-an-upgrade-to-a-secur)

RFC doc: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.42