# Node express js server returning HTTP 426 upgrade required

Tags: node.js

I have created sample express js hello world application listening on port 3000.
When application accessed using URL http//localhost:3000/ application run properly.
But if accessed using machine  name ,  http://fullmachinename:3000/ , getting HTTP 426 upgrade required response

Comment: Some info here: [Is HTTP status code 426 Upgrade Required only meant signal an upgrade to a secure channel is required?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873247/is-http-status-code-426-upgrade-required-only-meant-signal-an-upgrade-to-a-secur) and [426 UPGRADE REQUIRED](https://httpstatuses.com/426)

Answer (score 0):

Port is being used or blocked, switch to another port and try again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).